# modifying u-boot environment for alternating boot

Tags: embedded, embedded-linux, bootloader, boot, u-boot

I’ve got an embedded device where I would like to implement an alternating boot mechanism to make sure that an executable operating system is always present (e.g. after an invalid update) Therefore at every reboot the bootloader should switch between the partitions mmcblk1p1 and mmcblk1p2 .

- mmcblk1p1 – rootfs 1 (OS + Application (read only))
- mmcblk1p2 –
  rootfs 2 (OS + Application (read only) (mirrored))
- mmcblk1p3 - Data (rw)

To realise this I’ve enabled the bootcount variable in the u-boot config to increase bootcount +1 after every reboot (this is already working). My plan was to use the bootlimit mechanism provided by the bootloader (https://www.denx.de/wiki/DULG/UBootBootCountLimit) to call a function called altbootcmd to change the boot partition and to reset bootcount, but unfortunately the bootlimit mechanism is not supported for ARM processors:

So my plan is now to define a simple if else statement in the CONFIG_EXTRA_ENV_SETTINGS statement in the header file (that adds support fro my board) under */include/configs/board_xy_config.h* and then to compile the bootloader. (Explanatory notes: mmcpart is the number of the partition)

```c
#define CONFIG_EXTRA_ENV_SETTINGS        \
CONFIG_MFG_ENV_SETTINGS \
"if test ${bootcount} = 1; then " \
    "setenv mmcpart 1; " \
"else " \
    "if test ${bootcount} = 2; then " \
        "setenv mmcpart 2; " \
    "else " \
        "setenv mmcpart 1; " \
        "setenv bootcount 1; " \
    "fi;" \
"fi; " \
```

Unfortunately this approach also doesn't work. fw_printenv shows me that bootcount variable gets increased at every reboot, but neither the mmcpart variable nor the bootcount variable get changed after several reboots. I am manually able to switch between the partitions using “fw_setenv mmcpart x”, but it seems that the if else statement doesn't get called.

Does someone know what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: I would do a straightforward approach (not touching `bootcount` variable): just define your own variable and check it. But I think that the problem you encountered is due to missed `saveenv` call.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! Is there a certain reason why I shouldn't use the `bootcount` variable? The reason why I want to use bootcount is that in case of a kernel panic `bootcount` gets incremented (I use the kernel argument `panic=2` for this, which should trigger a reboot after 2 seconds). This ensures that if a partition is corrupted, I automatically boot into the working partition.

But you're right - I could also define my own variable that gets incremented +1 at every boot.. 

In any case, thank you for the advice about the missed saveenv call, I will add it tomorrow and test it!